# Android Application won't run on Device

Tags: android

Ive been playing around with android a bit, and followed a Text Message tutorial.
The Code that I entered is supposed to be able to send an sms, but not receive. 
When I try to run the application, it installs, starts, goes black and crashes before I see the screen. Does anybody know whats wrong? Also, when I create apps, very simple apps, with only a button, it also installs, starts but crashes. Is this common, even if there are no visual mistakes?

```
     import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.telephony.SmsManager;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class Message extends Activity {

Button sendSMS;
EditText msgTxt;
EditText numTxt;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.example.sms.R.layout.message);

    sendSMS = (Button) findViewById(com.example.sms.R.id.sendBtn);
    msgTxt = (EditText) findViewById(com.example.sms.R.id.editText2);
    numTxt = (EditText) findViewById(com.example.sms.R.id.numberTxt);
    sendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String myMsg = msgTxt.getText().toString();
            String theNumber = numTxt.getText().toString();

            }
    });
    }

    protected void sendMsg(String theNumber, String myMsg) {
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(theNumber, null, myMsg, null, null);
} }



     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numberTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sms"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name = "android.permission.SEND_SMS" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

   <activity android:name=".myclass" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>


    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

```
    03-16 18:09:41.669: D/AndroidRuntime(18171): Shutting down VM
    03-16 18:09:41.669: W/dalvikvm(18171): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught
     exception (group=0x419c12a0)
    03-16 18:09:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(18171): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-16 18:09:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(18171):
    java.lang.RuntimeException:               
    Unable       to   instantiate activity             
    {com.example.sms/com.example.sms.myclass}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  
   com.example.sms.myclass
    03-16 18:09:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(18171):    at  
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    03-16 18:09:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(18171):    at  
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
    03-16 18:09:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(18171):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
    03-16 18:09:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(18171):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
    03-16 18:09:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(18171):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-16 18:09:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(18171):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    03-16 18:09:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(18171):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
    03-16 18:09:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(18171):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    3-16 18:09:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(18171):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    03-16 18:09:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(18171):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
    03-16 18:09:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(18171):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
    03-16 18:09:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(18171):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-16 18:09:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(18171): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.sms.myclass
    03-16 18:09:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(18171):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
    03-16 18:09:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(18171):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    03-16 18:09:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(18171):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    03-16 18:09:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(18171):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
    03-16 18:09:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(18171):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2007)
    03-16 18:09:41.679: E/AndroidRuntime(18171):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

the name of your class is `Message` not `myclass`, change it into the manifest

from

```
<activity android:name=".myclass" android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

to

```
  <activity android:name=".Message" android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify `Activity` correctly in `Manifest`. You `Activity` is named `Message`, not `myclass`. Change this:

```
<activity android:name=".myclass" android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

to this:

```
<activity android:name=".Message" android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```